# Cache apache mod_write and php headers

Tags: php, apache, caching, mod-rewrite, header

I'm having a problem with php redirect (header) and mod_rewrite.

Here is how:

1 - I log into the system and wait time for the session expires.

2 - I click a link that has any rewriting (mod_rewrite set).
**Ex:** *www.page.com.br/product/25/product-name.html*

3 - In implementing the above file (products.php), PHP checks that the session expired and redirects to index.php?t=time() via header ("Location").

4 - After that, if the user clicks again in www.page.com.br/product/25/product-name.html,
mod_rewrite does not rewrite to the correct file (products.php) and maintains a cache that redirects back to index.php?t=time()

comments:

This only occurs with links that need rewriting and redirection link that occurred.

Add the function time () to make sure it is a cache and no redirects successive proof is that it keeps the t = time () in clicks later

Someone had this problem, or know of some kind of cache that this mod-rewrite generating this problem?

thanks
Rafael

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Are you doing a 302 or a 301 redirect? 301 is "moved permanently", which means the browser will automatically go to the 'new' page, without checking for changes. If you do a 302, it's a "moved temporarily", and the browser will check if the redirect is still in effect each time.

Comment: Thanks Mark, I forced myself to do the 302 redirect and still continues with the cache problem, noting that this occurs only with links that need mod_rewrite

Comment: You can tell mod_rewrite what kind of redirect it should do as well. `[R=302]` in the rewriterule should do it.

Comment: Marc, thanks again, I tried your suggestion, the cache problem did not occur, but he did not rewrite correctly, simply changed the link www.page.com.br/product/25/product-name.html by www. page.com.br/products.php?p=25, ie the re-writing was ignored.

Comment: [R = 302] is a redirect to the products.php page, so it works, but it's not just that I need, I need it to follow the rewrite and not redirect

Comment: @user819428 Turn URL Rewriting debugging ON and see the logs on WHY id does like that (if it does at all). I have never had anything like that with both Apache 2.2 and IIS 7. rewrite should ALWAYS work (I mean, no caching here). If you have any links that can prove that such caching may occur please show us (I will be very interested on reading this). Thnx